# Read output of spark-rowsimilarity analysis directly without writing it to file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am writing scala code to pull data from db and run spark-rowsimilarity analysis.
After running spark-rowsimilarity I want to read data returned by function directly write it back to mysql db. But I don't know how to read the data from indexeddataset returned by

```
val data = SimilarityAnalysis.rowSimilarityIDS(myIDs).
```

In debugger it shows datatype as Indexeddataset which contains (matrix,rowIDs,columnIds).

Thanks.